# Is a plant's own compost better for the plant?

Tags: plant-physiology

Does it make a difference if a plant is composted and used for its own compost ?
Meaning, let's say there is a plant "X" (example Cucumber)
Would it grow better if the compost was made from the "X" plant itself ?
Has there been a study on the same ?

Comment: There are a lot of studies about composting and plant vigor. Have you looked for a study? If so, what did you find out? Some **evidence** (not your claim to have done so) of prior resesarch is strongly recommended on this site, and lack thereof is a reason for close vote and down vote.

Comment: you should ask a farmer this question,they have studied this for som time(10 000 years+).